# How to edit legend labels in ggord (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, format

[My plot i am trying to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZUHp.png)

I am trying to edit the legend labels in [ggord](https://fawda123.github.io/ggord/reference/ggord.html) (not exactly ggplot)

I want to change "blamm" -> "Airborne"

&

"sccoos" -> "seawater"

The code I got me my plot!

```
library(ggord)
sample_types <- c("Airborne", "Seawater")
ggord(
  simpleRDA3,
  taxa_ord_meta$sample_type,
  xlims = c(-0.5, 1.1),
  ylims = c(-0.52, 1.1),
  repel = TRUE,
  grp_title = "Sample Type")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  ggtitle("Ordination by Distance Based Redundancy Analysis", "Community defining bacteria, within the Sea Surface-Atmospheric Boundary Layer")+
  labs(caption = str_wrap("Refer to Table # for details of specfic taxa. The 12 taxa represented are the top 6 most sifnficantly different, and the top 6 highest relatice abundance."))+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Try to create a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We lack the underlying data. That said, I guess you could us tranform your data before going to the plot, create a new column in your data.frame with the new names.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur, I was hoping there was a simple str_replce-type argument I could use within ggord(). 
I did get the result I was looking for using [mutate(sample_type = replace(sample_type, sample_type == "blamm", "Airborne")] and the same for my seawater sample.